# Why there's no need to allocate a memory space to store pointer returned from function?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* get_string(){
//    char* pointer = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    char* pointer = "string";
    printf("%s\n",pointer);
    return pointer;
}

int main(){
//    char* got = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    char* got = get_string();
    printf("%s\n",got);
//    free(got);
}
```

This block of code gives no warning in testing.
But my question is :
For the following lines of code,

```
    char* got = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    got = get_string();
```

Why the `malloc` here is not needed?
Why there's no need to allocate memory to store the pointer returned from the function?
I am a bit confused now.
Thank you.

Comment: `char* pointer = "string";` there is already memory allocated for `pointer`, and `pointer` is pointing to read only content, you can return it and pass it but cannot modify its contents

Comment: You do have a location to store the pointer.  The variable `got` is given enough space on the stack to store a pointer.  It's no different than `int x = 5`, where space is provided to store an integer.

Comment: Note that `char *got = malloc(...); got = get_string()` is a memory leak, since you've lost the value returned by malloc.  It's like `int x = 5; x = 7` in the sense that the 5 is lost.

Comment: Note the differences between copying strings (`strcpy()` et al) and assigning pointers.  You can't assign arrays directly.

Answer (score 2):

Take an example:

```
int a = 5;
a =6;
```

now, the value `5` is lost.
Same with your case, too. The pointer returned by `malloc()`, and stored into `got`, will be **overwritten** by the pointer returned by the function call `get_string()`. So there will be memory leak.

Remember, you're assigning a value to a variable (of pointer type), and for that variable, `got`, memory is already allocated. You need to make sure that the value of `got`, i.e., the address held by `got` points to a valid memory location before you can read/write to/into that location.

Answer (score 1):

In C

```
const char* my_str = "my str";
```

creates creates a string "my str" in global static memory and the creates a pointer on the stack that points to that memory. Since "my str" exists for the life of the process, it is safe to return a pointer to it. However if you did:

```
const char my_str[] = "my str";
return my_str;
```

You will hit undefined (bad) behaviour. This is because the latter case allocates "my str" on the stack in the function and once the function returns "my str" is popped off the stack. Any pointer returned will be pointing to garbage.

In C++ you can only assign string literal to a `const char*`. C allows you to assign a string literal to a `char*` but I don't believe writing to the dereferenced pointer is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a pointer as a **variable** that stores values of type **address**.

**malloc** is a function that returns the **address** of a place in memory that can store the desired size passed as parameter.

Once the variables get out of scope (when you reach '**}**' that closes the first '**{**' that came before that variable declaration) you lose access to them, their location in memory will become invalid.

What **malloc** does is keep that place in memory valid until you release it with **free**.

So if you already called malloc and want to update a pointer, all you have to do is assign that value (address) to the pointer.